# Close JFrame and open another JFrame from another class

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I am pretty new to Java. I have this particular issue that have kept me from moving to the next phase of my project. I want to close a JFrame from my main class from another class and open another jFrame on button click. I have been able to open the second JFrame on button click, but can't close the first JFrame. I am working with **Netbeans**.

**NOTE:** I'm trying to have separate codes for views and controller using an MVC design pattern.

Here are my codes.

**LoginPage (Main class)**

```
package auth;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class LoginPage extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public static LoginPage lp = new LoginPage(); 
    
    public LoginPage() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here: Cancel button
        System.exit(0);
    }                                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here: Login button
        String uname = jTextField1.getText();
        String pword = jPasswordField1.getText();
        
        try {
            LoginController.collectUserData(uname, pword);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new LoginPage().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

and the other class

**LoginController**

```
package auth;

import dbconnect.dbconnect;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LoginController extends javax.swing.JFrame { 
    
    public static void collectUserData(String uname, String pword) throws SQLException {
        Login user = new Login();
        user.setUsername(uname);
        user.setPass(pword);
        checkDatabaseAndLogin(user);
    }

    public static void checkDatabaseAndLogin(Login test) throws SQLException {
        JFrame rootPane;
        if (test.getUsername().equals("")||test.getPass().equals("")) {
            rootPane = new JFrame();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Some fields are empty", "Error", 1);
        } else {
            try {
                //LoginPage lp = new LoginPage();
                Connection con = dbconnect.connect();
                PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from test where username=? and pass=?");
                pst.setString(1, test.getUsername());
                pst.setString(2, test.getPass());
                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                                
                if (rs.next()) {
                    String un = rs.getString("username");
                    //System.out.println(un);
                    PatronPage pt = new PatronPage(un);
                    pt.setVisible(true);  //Code to open the new window
                    LoginPage.lp.dispose(); //Code to close the old window
                } else {
                    rootPane = new JFrame();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Username or Password do not match record", "Login error", 1);
                } 
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(""+ex);
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Of course there are other system generated codes in Netbeans I removed, I just provided the chunk of code that I feel are relevant to the solution. **Please help out, I'm stuck**.

Comment: See JFrame.setDefaultClosingAction(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)

Comment: Your "controller" should not be extending from `JFrame`.  When the user has been successfully authenticated, you should have a event notification which you send to the login view, it will then close it self, same thing if the authentication fails, you'd send an appropriate event to the view and it would decide how best to notify the user.  I'd also discourage the use of `static` - this isn't going to help you

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72157369/login-system-java-and-postgresql/72157680#72157680)

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer for your comment. Can you please go a step further to give an example using my own codes. I checked the link, they context there are not very similar. I am pretty new to Java.

Comment: Short answer is no - because your code is wrong - the example I've provide is basically the same thing you want to do, just done (slightly) better :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LoginPage` instance that you are "closing" in your `LoginController` class with the line

```
LoginPage.lp.dispose();
```

is not the instance which you initially displayed with

```
new LoginPage().setVisible(true);
```

I am afraid your whole approach to creating a Swing UI is wrong. Maybe work through the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) first.

Comment: How do I get the instance that is displayed. I'm trying to have separate codes for views and controller using an MVC design pattern.

Comment: You would need to either pass the instance of `LoginPage` that calls the `LoginController` to the controller or store the instance somewhere where the controller can access it. However, my advice would be to do neither. I think multiple frames are not a good UX. Instead create one `JFrame` instance that displays the login components and after the user logged in, replace the login components with the components that should be shown next. There are multiple ways to do that. E.g. you could use `CardLayout` or you could actually `remove` the login components and `add` the next set of components.